# Validation fails when multiple <form> tags are present in the same HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple `form` tags in my html doc and want to validate them. However the validation function won't give any result. Tried
adding name field to the `<form>` the `validation()` does not return any result.

When I use validation with only one `<form>` the result is correct.
here are the two form tags:

```
<div id="pinfo">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Information</legend>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter name">
            <br><br>
            Email:
            <input type="email" name="eamil" value="Enter email id">
            <br><br>
            Confirm email id:
            <input type="text" name="cemail" value="">
            <br><br>
            Password:
            <input type="password" name="pass" value="">
            <br><br>
            Confirm password:
            <input type="password" name="cpass" value="">
            <br><br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="linfo">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Location and Contact</legend>
            Location:
            State:
```

<!more code ahead>

```
<script> 
function validateForm() { 
var eid = document.forms["loginform"]["emailid"].value; 
  if (eid == null || eid == "") { 
     alert("Email id must be entered."); 
     return false; 
   } 
var pwd = document.forms["loginform"]["password"].value; 
 if (pwd == null || pwd == ""){ 
     alert("Please enter the password."); 
     return false; 
  } 
var p = document.forms["locinfo"]["pno"].value; 
 if (p == null || p=="") { 
     alert("Please enter the phone no."); 
     return false; 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: where it is your javascript code which you tried?

Comment: <script>
function validateForm() {
    var eid = document.forms["loginform"]["emailid"].value;
     if (eid == null || eid == "") {
        alert("Email id must be entered.");
        return false;
    }
    var pwd = document.forms["loginform"]["password"].value;
     if (pwd == null || pwd == ""){
         alert("Please enter the password.");
         return false;
    }
    var p = document.forms["locinfo"]["pno"].value;
     if (p == null || p=="") {
         alert("Please enter the phone no.");
         return false;
}
</script>

Comment: i have added "locinfo" as the name of the form

Comment: Seems your code is broken, please paste properly or how are you calling validate method

Comment: can you post everything in a same?

Comment: I think you forget to call `validateForm()` when the form is submitted add `onsubmit="return validateForm();"` inside youe form tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Validating Form Fields Using JavaScript in FrontPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218652%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code.
You have not given form name as "loginform" which you are using in validation function.
And second thing you missed is "onsubmit" attribute on form element

Here is working code for you

```js
function validateForm() {
    console.log(document.forms["loginform"])
    var eid = document.forms["loginform"]["eamil"].value;
    if (eid == null || eid == "") {
        alert("Email id must be entered.");
        return false;
    }
    var pwd = document.forms["loginform"]["pass"].value;
    if (pwd == null || pwd == "") {
        alert("Please enter the password.");
        return false;
    }
    /*var p = document.forms["locinfo"]["pno"].value;
    if (p == null || p == "") {
        alert("Please enter the phone no.");
        return false;
    }*/
}
```

```html
<div id="pinfo">
<form method="post" name="loginform" action="/" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal Information</legend>
Name:                                                          
<input type="text" name="name" value="">  
<br><br> 
Email:
<input type="email" name="eamil" value="">
<br><br>
Confirm email id:
<input type="text" name="cemail" value="">
<br><br>
Password:
<input type="password" name="pass" value="">
<br><br>
Confirm password:
<input type="password" name="cpass" value="">
<br><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```